# Radiance: How does the focus of a "spotlight" work?

Tags: light, lighting

I can't get a spotlight in Radiance to work.

The doc states:

> The spotlight primitive type is used for self-luminous surfaces that
>   require a directed output. It is defined with red, green and blue
>   radiance values as well as an orientation ( output direction ) vector
>   and a full cone angle ( in degrees ). The orientation vector
>   determines the distance of effective focus behind the source centre (
>   ie the focal length).

What exactly does "effective focus" mean? Isn't this the same as the opening angle?

I tried something like

```
void spotlight spot_light
0
0
3 128 128 128
```

or

```
void spotlight spot_light
0
0
3 1000 1000 1000 5 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some explanation [here](http://radsite.lbl.gov/radiance/digests_html/v2n3.html#SPOTLIGHTS):

> The focal length produces only a subtle difference as it shifts the
>   effective position of the source behind the actual emitting surface. A
>   real spotlight has the effect of changing its falloff to being
>   something less than r^-2 (where r is the distance to the emitter) in
>   this way. The actual falloff is closer to (r+e)^-2, where e is the
>   focal length of the spotlight's optics.  It is a minor concern, I
>   admit.